# How to build a efficient Load Balance?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, nginx, load-balancing, virtualmin

How to build a efficient Load Balance?

the reason is the very heavy database MYSQL...

a website with 30,000 articles.
I thought about separating the database, creating a file.         But I don't know if it's possible with the same URL address.

My intention is to make a Load Balance that is easy to implement and performs well.

### System:

```
Linux Ubuntu Server 20.04
virtualmin
Nginx
PHP 7.4
mysql
WordPress
```

*I'm having trouble finding updated information about Load Balance.
Although the questions clear some doubts, but they are out of date and many unanswered...
Look:* [link][1]
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5Bload-balancing%5D%20Wordpress

Comment: I do not think the direction of load balancing of database will solve your problem, I think it gone over complicating things. There are several strategies like caching, more database compute power, maybe you are using shared hosting

Comment: I don't use shared hosting. I use a VPS with 3 cores and 12 GB of RAM.

Could you point me to some possibilities to have a faster bank?

Comment: That is fine, consider caching, that said you need to analyse the core problem. 30000 article should not be a big deal. For instance if your Storage is SSD will mean a lot for database.

Comment: Would it be possible to put more than one database?
It would be advisable... For example... Every 3 years...
Every 3 years would have a database...

Could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a WordPress expert, but with my basic knowledge about WordPress (I have my personal blog in WordPress), I can put an answer together that might enlighten you.

There could be many reasons any website is slow, in your case WordPress website. 30000 articles as you mention in your question is not a big deal for a database with the mentioned resources.

In your question, you come up with a solution to split databases, but I am pretty sure even if you split databases into multiple databases you will still have the same issue.

I would rather start analyzing the website to find out why it is slow. There are many factors that can cause the slowness of a website. Otherwise, you will solve random issues that do not bring any value to your end goal.

To analyze your website, there are some online tooling like:

https://pagespeed.web.dev

or

https://tools.pingdom.com

Both sites offer some suggestions on how to improve your performance.

I would also parallel to that also read some articles about How to optimize your WordPress (one [example](https://www.dreamhost.com/blog/optimize-wordpress-website-speed)).

- Choose a Quality Hosting Plan (Consider a provider with an SSD disk, good network speed, and no shared hosting)
- Always Keep Your Plugins, Themes, and WordPress Software Updated
- Implement Caching to Reduce the Number of Requests Your Site Handles
- Use Image Optimization to Make Your Media Files Smaller
- Minify and Compress Your Website’s Files
- Use a Content Delivery Network to Deliver Your Site’s Large Files
- Only Use High-Quality Themes and Plugins
- Delete Unused Themes and Plugins
- Clean Up Your Media Library and Post Revisions
- Optimize Your Databases

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention and answering questions. It was important to take that issue.